# Calculating $\int_C(x-y)dz$

Tags: integration

Let C be the curve defined by the intersection of $z=x^2+y^2$ and the plane $z-2x-2y=1$. We orient C with the counterclockwise orientation as seen from the point (0,0,10) and calculate:
$$\int_C(x-y)dz$$

We need to use Stokes' theorem here, which I know how to do, but I'm not sure what we pick as the normal vector?

Comment: Basically you have a cone and a plane intercepting the cone. The normal vector will be a vector perpendicular to that plane ($\vec{n}_{\pm}=\pm$ (-2,-2,1) for example). The thing is I'm not sure what you exactly mean by "as seen from the point (0,0,10)". In my opinion by taking the scalar product of the vector $\vec{v}$ going from (0,0,10) to some point on the plane, say (0,0,1) and by checking if its scalar product with the normal vector is positive or negative will tell you which one to choose... But again, it all depends on how you define "as seen from".

Comment: I just re read your question. It says counterclockwise, I had not paid attention to this before. The scalar product should be negative. I let you picture the situation (it's easy if you consider that the contour is a circle, that you're exactly above it, and that the vector $\vec{v}$ goes from you to the center of the circle")